# Meteor Clear Client Subscription

Tags: meteor, publish-subscribe

Dear all,

```
   Template.tmp_detail_campaign_code_batch.events({
        'click .ancProdCodePagination': function (e) {
            Meteor.subscribe('ItemPage', Number*10,10)
        }
    });
```

Its definition:

```
Meteor.publish('ItemPage', function(skipItem, takeItem){
    return Item.find({},{
        skip : skipItem,
        limit : takeItem
    }); }
```

When I click .ancProdCodePagination, the amount of subscribed Items keep increasing by 10. For pagination, I'd like to make the amount stay at 10, but with different Items for each click.

What should I do?

Answer (score 5):

You just need to `stop` the previous subscription first, which will involve storing the handle that it returns somewhere:

```
var itemSub;

Template.tmp_detail_campaign_code_batch.events({
    'click .ancProdCodePagination': function (e) {
        if (itemSub)
            itemSub.stop();
        itemSub = Meteor.subscribe('ItemPage', Number*10,10);
    }
});
```

From [the docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_subscribe), the `stop` method does this:

> Cancel the subscription. This will typically result in the server directing the client to remove the subscription's data from the client's cache.

Comment: how can we make the `itemSub` persistent for clients session? storing the `itemSub` in Session trims off the methods, and we can't call `stop` on it.